# Bootstrap Tooltips - can It Wrap Text?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I want to display some text in a `tooltip` but it overflows outside of `tooltip` itself. I suspect that Iv'e made a mess with a certain **css** property that makes it to, could some1 point me out to the fix that should be applied?
it looks like this:

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you add your code snippet in a jsFiddle or here?

Comment: thanks for trying, got it fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the problem is that the tooltip element inherited from one of it's perent the "white-space: nowrap" property.
it's fixed now :)